# Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I have a Python (2.7) app which is started in my dockerfile:

```
CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

*main.py* prints some strings when it is started and goes into a loop afterwards:

```
print "App started"
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

As long as I start the container with the -it flag, everything works as expected:

```
$ docker run --name=myapp -it myappimage
> App started
```

And I can see the same output via logs later:

```
$ docker logs myapp
> App started
```

If I try to run the same container with the -d flag, the container seems to start normally, but I can't see any output:

```
$ docker run --name=myapp -d myappimage
> b82db1120fee5f92c80000f30f6bdc84e068bafa32738ab7adb47e641b19b4d1
$ docker logs myapp
$ (empty)
```

But the container still seems to run;

```
$ docker ps
Container Status ...
myapp     up 4 minutes ...
```

Attach does not display anything either:

```
$ docker attach --sig-proxy=false myapp
(working, no output)
```

Any ideas whats going wrong? Does "print" behave differently when ran in background?

Docker version:

```
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/arm
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Answer (score 605, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to see Python output when running daemonized in Docker, thanks to @ahmetalpbalkan over at [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12447#issuecomment-94417192). Answering it here myself for further reference :

Using unbuffered output with

```
CMD ["python","-u","main.py"]
```

instead of

```
CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

solves the problem; you can see the output now (both, stderr and stdout) via

```
docker logs myapp
```

---

why `-u` [ref](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12447#issuecomment-94417192)

```
- print is indeed buffered and docker logs will eventually give you that output, just after enough of it will have piled up
- executing the same script with python -u gives instant output as said above
- import logging + logging.warning("text") gives the expected result even without -u
```

what it means by `python -u` ref. > python --help | grep -- -u

```
-u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
```

Comment: -u seems to work for me, but is there some documentation somewhere with a description of what it actually does?

Comment: As suggested by other answers, you can try setting environment variable `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` in case the `-u` flag does not work.

Comment: This was my problem too. For a more detailed explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24183941/562883

Comment: Some more about `-u` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Comment: Works like a dream on python3, while setting PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0 wasnt helping.

Comment: Be aware `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0`  is no silver bullet. It comes with a performance penalty.

Comment: This worked for me using conda. What was weird was if the script failed, I would get the exception printed to the terminal. If the script ran fine, I got no output from my prints. This fixed that!

Comment: Thanks This helped us to start with debugging on prod

Comment: 3 hours of my life I lost to this. Thanks, you're a gem ✨

Answer (score 160):

In my case, running Python with `-u` didn't change anything. What did the trick, however, was to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` as environment variable:

```
docker run --name=myapp -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -d myappimage
```

[Edit]: Updated `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` to `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` after Lars's comment. This doesn't change the behavior and adds clarity.

Comment: In my case, adding `-e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` helps.

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head off a wall for hours, and couldn't get logs to work even with `-u`. Your solution fixed it for me on Docker for Mac with Django

Comment: i think this is a better solution, that we don't have to rebuild the docker image  to see the outputs

Comment: This is great thanks. Its worth mentioning that this just needs to be a non empty character to work according to the docs [PYTHONUNBUFFERED](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)

Comment: Worked for docker-compose interface. Would have never guessed

Comment: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` is misleading b/c it suggests that unbuffering is disabled. Instead it's enabled b/c python looks for a _non-empty_ string. That said, better use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` which has the same effect but doesn't lead to wrong assumptions.

Comment: The value of `0` didn't work on Python 3.8. I had to use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to make it work.

Answer (score 47):

If you want to add your print output to your Flask output when running `docker-compose up`, add the following to your docker compose file.

```
web:
  environment:
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Someone able to elaborate why this variable not works when divined in the Dockerfile and not in the docker-compose file? I thought this shouldn't matter but works like a charm!

Comment: @0x78f1935 are you perhaps using an `ARG` directive instead of an `ENV` one? It should work in the dockerfile as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ Any Idea as to why this might not work?

Answer (score 41):

See [this article](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering) which explain detail reason for the behavior:

> There are typically three modes for buffering:
>
> - If a file descriptor is unbuffered then no buffering occurs whatsoever, and function calls that read or write data occur immediately (and will block).
> - If a file descriptor is fully-buffered then a fixed-size buffer is used, and read or write calls simply read or write from the buffer. The buffer isn’t flushed until it fills up.
> - If a file descriptor is line-buffered then the buffering waits until it sees a newline character. So data will buffer and buffer until a \n is seen, and then all of the data that buffered is flushed at that point in time. In reality there’s typically a maximum size on the buffer (just as in the fully-buffered case), so the rule is actually more like “buffer until a newline character is seen or 4096 bytes of data are encountered, whichever occurs first”.

And GNU libc (glibc) uses the following rules for buffering:

```
Stream               Type          Behavior
stdin                input         line-buffered
stdout (TTY)         output        line-buffered
stdout (not a TTY)   output        fully-buffered
stderr               output        unbuffered
```

So, if use `-t`, from [docker document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground), it will allocate a pseudo-tty, then `stdout` becomes `line-buffered`, thus `docker run --name=myapp -it myappimage` could see the one-line output.

And, if just use `-d`, no tty was allocated, then, `stdout` is `fully-buffered`, one line `App started` surely not able to flush the buffer.

Then, use `-dt` to `make stdout line buffered` or add `-u` in python to `flush the buffer` is the way to fix it.

Answer (score 21):

Since I haven't seen this answer yet:

You can also flush stdout after you print to it:

```
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print('cleaner is up', flush=True)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me, stupid that this needs to be there, but works great now.

Comment: This worked for me as well. None of the envar methods, nor the "-u" method worked for me.

Comment: PS: if you have several `print` and then you flush at the last one, you get to see all the previous `print` up to the one with `flush=True`.

Answer (score 20):

Try to add these two environment variables to your solution `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` and `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Comment: why would you need `PYTHONIOENCODING`?

Comment: To get away with no ASCII chars.

Answer (score 8):

You can see logs on detached image if you change `print` to `logging`.

main.py:

```
import time
import logging
print "App started"
logging.warning("Log app started")
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7-stretch
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

Comment: nice. tip: use Python 3.

Comment: question is in Python 2 (print statement without parenthesis) therefore am using 2 here. Although it is exactly the same behaviour on Python3.6 so thanks for a tip ;)

Answer (score 7):

If anybody is running the python application with conda you should add `--no-capture-output` to the command since conda buffers to stdout by default.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "my-app", "python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Now it logs to the interactive console as well as when using the `docker log` command!

Answer (score 5):

I had to use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in my docker-compose.yml file to see the output from django runserver.

Answer (score 4):

As a quick fix, try this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
# some code
print("App started", file=sys.stderr)
```

This works for me when I encounter the same problems. But, to be honest, I don't know why does this error happen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Tried replacing all prints with your version, unfortunately it did not work for me, still can't get any output via docker logs (changing between sys.stderr / sys.stdout does has no visible result). Is this a docker bug?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57801848/6394722), the reason is: stderr was unbuffered, so you can make it fix with your solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't using `docker-compose` and just normal `docker` instead, you can add this to your `Dockerfile` that is hosting a flask app

```
ARG FLASK_ENV="production"
ENV FLASK_ENV="${FLASK_ENV}" \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED="true"

CMD [ "flask", "run" ]
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `python manage.py runserver` for a Django application, adding environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` solve my problem. `print('helloworld', flush=True)` also works for me.

However, `python -u` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use visual studio code with docker extension to create Dockerfile in python automatically.

By default it have this line

```
# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

it works and show logs when container run in detached mode, so I think that's the preferred way. I use python 3.11

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we redirect it to a specific file (by mounting a volume from host and writing it to that file).

Adding a tty using -t is also fine. You need to pick it up in docker logs.

Using large log outputs, I did not have any issue with buffer storing all without putting it in dockers log.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ends up here, I tried a bunch of these solutions but none worked for me. In the end I needed to propertly configure my logger by adding

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

before I instantiated my logger instance

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

This worked perfectly and I didn't have to make any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the answers here worked.

In order to see messages my Python program was printing to stdout within a Docker container I had to add:

`tty: True`

for my Python service in my docker `compose.yaml`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#tty