# Kubernetes + Minikube - How to see all stdout output?

Tags: ruby, kubernetes, minikube

I'm running a Ruby app on Kubernetes with Minikube.

However, whenever I look at the logs I don't see the output I would have seen in my terminal when running the app locally.

I presume it's because it only shows stderr?

What can I do to see all types of console logs (e.g. from `puts` or `raise`)?

On looking around is this something to do with it being in detached mode - see the Python related issue: [Logs in Kubernetes Pod not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969743/logs-in-kubernetes-pod-not-showing-up)

Thanks.

=

As requested - here is the deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sample
          image: someregistry
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
          args: ["bundle exec rake sample:default --trace"]
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: sample
          - secretRef:
              name: sample
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regsecret
```

Comment: on openshift k8, `oc logs -f my-service-1.0.1`

Answer (score 6):

As shown in this article, `kubectl logs pod apod` should show you stdout and stderr for a pod deployed in a minikube.

> By default in Kubernetes, Docker is configured to write a container's stdout and stderr to a file under /var/log/containers on the host system

[Kubernetes adds](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#system-component-logs):

> There are two types of system components: those that run in a container and those that do not run in a container.
>   For example:
>
> - The Kubernetes scheduler and kube-proxy run in a container.
> - The kubelet and container runtime, for example Docker, do not run in containers.

And:

> - On machines with systemd, the kubelet and container runtime write to journald.
> - If systemd is not present, they write to `.log` files in the `/var/log` directory.
>
> Similarly to the container logs, system component logs in the /var/log directory should be rotated.
>   In Kubernetes clusters brought up by the kube-up.sh script, those logs are configured to be rotated by the logrotate tool daily or once the size exceeds 100MB.

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/59b1aae2adcfe4f06270b99a2789012ed64bec1f/4d0ad/images/docs/user-guide/logging/logging-node-level.png]

Comment: I tried `kubectl logs mypodname-7f74cb6f54-hr67v -n the-namespace` and it shows me the same log as in Minikube i.e. not including stdout

Comment: @userMod2 is there any permission issue, as in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19616#issuecomment-174492543? Can you try a docker exec to test it out?

Comment: No permissions issue.

Comment: @userMod2 Would a `kubectl describe pod aPod -n anamespace` returns any clues?

Answer (score 3):

> I presume it's because it only shows stderr?

Not really, unless something specific is disabled in your container or pod spec. I assume you are using Docker so then the default it's to output [stdout and stderr](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) and that's what you see when you do a [`kubectl logs <pod-name>`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level)

> What can I do to see all types of console logs (e.g. from puts or raise)?

You should see them in the container logs. It would help to post your pod or deployment definition.

Comment: added the deployment.yaml above

Comment: Also when you say container logs - I presume pod logs is the same? i.e. `kubectl logs mypodname-7f74cb6f54-hr67v -n my-namespace`