# Kubernetes logging level --v

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes to run a python script as a cron job. The issue is that I am not seeing the output of the script (Which can take a while to run) until after the job finishes. I suspect this is due to the logging level (--v option) but I cannot for the life of my find either the documentation for it (it default to --v=0). IF I want to increase the verbosity of what is outputted, does anyone know the value of 'INFO' or 'TRACE' (or what the values are/where they are defined)? Thank for any help in advance.

Edit: has anyone successfully gotten a python file to log to a Kubernetes pod while the pod was running? If so did you use print() or a different logging framework?

Comment: Could it be the behavior of your python script? Are you sure it's going to stdout?

Comment: @thisguy123 thank you. I think I am logging to stdout, I am using a standard print() statement in python (which to my knowledge always logs to stdout). Whenever I run the script locally it certainly logs to stdout. I also tried logging to stderr, but no use-still showing "The selected container has not logged any messages yet."

Comment: @thisguy123 The odd part is that I do see the logs, after my script finishes running (I am doing a print() -> sleep in a for loop a finite number of times). When the pod encounters crashbackLoop (i.e. when the script finishes) the logs get dumped to the log file. Is there a way to have the logs show up while the container is running?

Comment: For reference I created an extremely simple script to test this:
`
import sys
import time


def do_run():
    print("Hello world1")
    print("hello world error", file=sys.stderr)
    time.sleep(120)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_run()
`

Answer (score 4):

According to Kubernetes [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ),

```
If you don't see much useful in the logs, you could try turning on 
verbose logging on the Kubernetes component you suspect has a problem 
using --v or --vmodule, to at least level 4. See 
https://github.com/golang/glog for more details.
```

Comment: do you know if that is logging from the pod itself? Or just logging from a Kubernetes component (as I think it indicates)? I am trying to get logs from my pod while my pod is running.

Comment: @fylie, the link you posted is outdated now. However, I found a copy on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160121210548/https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause. Specifically, found it at [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) . The solution is to set the following environmental variable: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0 . It was not that the print statement was not being displayed, it was that the print statement was being buffered. Doing the above will solve the issue. Thank you @thisguy17 and @fylie for assisting.