# passing url as arguments in python when running docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, command-line-arguments

I want to pass an GCP storage URL as argument when running my docker image, so that it can pull my csv file from my storage and print the dataset .

Below is my dockerfile

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM continuumio/miniconda3


# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip install scikit-learn==0.20.2 firefly-python==0.1.15
RUN pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["pre.py"]
```

I tried running the docker image by below command and getting below error

```
docker run preprocess:v1 "https://storage.googleapis.com/MYBucket/app/Model/IrisClassifier.sav"
```

.

```
python: can't open file 'https://storage.googleapis.com/MYBucket/app/Model/IrisClassifier.sav': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```
import os
import argparse
from google.cloud import storage
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from urllib.request import urlopen

def parse_arguments():
    print('entered parse arg')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('data_dir', type=str, help='GCSpath')
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
    print('Argument passed')
    print(os.getcwd())
    print('STARTING CLOUD RETRIVAL')
    print('*****client initialized')
    dataset_load = joblib.load(urlopen(args.dat_dir))
    print('*****loaded Dataset')
    print(dataset_load)


def main(_):
    print("Prior to entering arg")
    parse_arguments()
```

I want to pass a similar GCP bucket when running my docker image
https://storage.googleapis.com/MYBucket/app/Model/IrisClassifier.sav

Answer (score 0):

you need to change all your `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` at first:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip install scikit-learn==0.20.2 firefly-python==0.1.15
RUN pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "pre.py"]
```

then you can pass your `URL`.

The Problem with your setup is:

docker will start the entrypoint and that is `python` and with your command you overwrite the CMD wich will give you:

```
python YOUR_URL
```

**Update**

I do not know if you add if statement to run the main def but here how you schould edit the script:

```
def main():
    print("Prior to entering arg")
    parse_arguments()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I cant understand , can you please explain as I am new to docker

Comment: `docker run preprocess:v1 YOUR_URL` will overwrite the `CMD` in your image therefore you will end up with `python YOUR_URL` without `pre.py` and that  what the error you becom is about

Comment: I edited the dockerfile as you siad: ENTRYPOINT ["python","pre.py"]
But now there is no output when I run the docker image
docker run -d  preprocess:v5 https://storage.googleapis.com/MyBucket/app/Model/iris.csv
As you see in my python code , even the print statements which I have used for logs are not printing

Comment: that is an other problem see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker

Comment: I have given ENTRYPOINT ["python","-u","pre.py"] as you said but still I cant no output.. also I can see logs as the container is stopped

Comment: I ran the below:
docker run --name=prepy -it  preprocess:v6 https://storage.googleapis.com/MyBucket/app/Model/iris.csv

docker logs prepy
I dont get any logs

Comment: you may start your script locally without docker to see what comes at first