# Using Environment Variables with HELM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I plan to upgrade my project to HELM.

I have many environment variables that I have defined in deployment.yaml.

Best practice is it best to define the environment variables in the values.yaml file or the templates / deployment.yaml drop?

Can you help if there is a sample application you use?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: My answers are based on Helm 3. So let's get to it:

- #1: No, in your values.yaml you define the static/default values. It's not the best approach to let static values in your template files (like deployment.yaml). To override the values of values.yaml The best practice is to use [--set KEY=VALUE](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) file. In this case, is totally possible to get the environment variable.
- #2: Can you give an example? Yes, sure.

For example, I want to install Elasticsearch on my cluster using helm so I use the command:

```
helm install elastic/elasticsearch --version 7.8.0
```

But I do not want to use the default values of the chart. So I went to https://hub.helm.sh/charts/elastic/elasticsearch and https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.8/elasticsearch/values.yaml, saw what's possible to change, then I create the command:

```
helm install elastic/elasticsearch --set minimumMasterNodes=1 --set protocol=https  --version 7.8.0
```

But in my CD tool, the minimum master nodes are different values and since this is an environment variable I changed my command line to this:

```
helm install elastic/elasticsearch --set minimumMasterNodes=$MIN_MASTER_NODES --set protocol=https  --version 7.8.0
```

So, as a result, the command above will run with no problem in your CD tool once the MIN_MASTER_NODES environment variable is provided correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `values.yaml` to define environment vars is totally up to you. Is the value static? I'd have no problem leaving it in the deployment yaml. If it's a secret you should manage it either with k8s secrets or input it when you use `helm install --set-value..` If the value is dynamic and is changed often or could be changed in the future that is the true use for `values.yaml` imo

Answer (score 1):

There's four possible places you could set environment variables, and each has a use.

1. Is the value **essentially fixed, any time you'd run the container in any environment**?  For example, consider [setting a Python application to not buffer its log output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) or specifying the container-internal port number.  Set these in the image's `Dockerfile`:

   ```bash
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
   ENV PORT=8000
   ```
2. Is the value **more or less fixed, any time you'd run the container in Kubernetes**?  Or, can you **reliably calculate the value**?  In these cases, you can set the value directly in your `templates/deployment.yaml` file, maybe with Helm templating.

   ```yaml
   env:
     - name: COORDINATOR_HOST
       value: {{ .Release.Name }}-coordinator  # another Service in the same chart
     - name: DATABASE_DRIVER
       value: postgresql                       # this chart doesn't support MySQL
   ```
3. Does the value have a **sensible default, but needs to be overridden sometimes**?  Put it in your chart's `values.yaml`.

   ```yaml
   # concurrency specifies the maximum number of concurrent tasks
   # to launch.
   concurrency: 4
   ```

   This needs to be repeated in the `templates/deployment.yaml` as well

   ```yaml
   env:
     - name: CONCURRENCY
       value: {{ quote .Values.concurrency }}
   ```
4. Is the value **only available at deployment time**; or do you need to **override one of these defaults**?  Use the `helm install -f` option to provide a per-environment value

   ```yaml
   databaseHost: myapp-pg.qa.example.com
   ```

   or the similar `helm install --set` option.  If it's reasonable to include a default value, also do so as in the previous example, but if not, you can use the `required` template function to give a reasonable error.

   ```yaml
   env:
     - name: DATABASE_HOST
       value: {{ .Values.databaseHost | required "a databaseHost must be provided" }}
   ```

You can use any or all of these options, depending on the specific values, even within the same chart.

The one pattern I don't particularly recommend is giving an open-ended list of environment variables (or other raw Kubernetes YAML) in the values file.  As an operator, this is hard to consume, and it especially doesn't interact well with the `helm install --set` option.  I tend to prefer listing out each configurable option in the Helm values file, and would modify the `templates/*.yaml` (maybe behind a deploy-time flag) if I needed more advanced customization.