# docker log don't show python print output

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Django Proj running in Docker Container

My `Debug=True`

but docker up logging doesn't show any `print('xxxx')` output.

Is there a way to fix it? thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a long search I found this https://serverfault.com/a/940357

Add `flush=True`

```py
print(datetime.now(), flush=True)
```

Or add `PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1` to docker-compose.yml which is added by PyCharm by default

```yaml
version: '3.6'

services:

  test:
    ....
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1  # <---
    ....
```