# Python program hangs when using multiprocessing Process and psutil while measuring the process

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, multiprocessing

I am trying to benchmark training MNIST between host OS and docker containerization.
To do performance check, I am using Python's psutil.

If I train on the host OS, the training goes fine. But doing this on docker with 8gb shared memory hangs at the beginning of the training
  `0%|                                                   | 0/938 [00:00<?, ?it/s]`

Here is what my function that uses multiprocessing and psutil looks like

```
def check_usage(system_info, p):
    system_info['cpu_percent'].append(p.cpu_percent())
    system_info['ram_percent'].append(p.memory_percent())
    system_info['cpu_threads'].append(p.num_threads())
    system_info['memory_rss'].append(p.memory_full_info().rss / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_vms'].append(p.memory_full_info().vms / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_shared'].append(p.memory_full_info().shared / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_data'].append(p.memory_full_info().data / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_swap'].append(p.memory_full_info().swap / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_uss'].append(p.memory_full_info().uss / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['memory_pss'].append(p.memory_full_info().pss / 1024 / 1024)
    system_info['swap_memory_used'].append(p.memory_full_info().swap / 1024 / 1024)

def monitor(target):
    worker_process = mp.Process(target=target)
    worker_process.start()
    p = psutil.Process(worker_process.pid)

    system_info = {
        'cpu_percent': [],
        'ram_percent': [],
        'cpu_threads': [],
        'memory_rss': [],
        'memory_vms': [],
        'memory_shared': [],
        'memory_data': [],
        'memory_swap': [],
        'memory_uss': [],
        'memory_pss': [],
        'swap_memory_used': []
    }
    # log cpu usage of `worker_process` every 10 ms
    while worker_process.is_alive():
        time.sleep(sleep_interval)
        check_usage(system_info, p)
    worker_process.join()
    return system_info
```

**Function that calls above**

```
sleep_interval = 0.5
training_val = monitor(target=run_model)
```

**run_model**

```
def run_model():
    # Train
    start_time = time.time()
    per_epoch_train_duration = []
    per_epoch_with_val_duration = []
    for _ in range(epochs):
        epoch_time = time.time()
        model.train()
        for _, (data, targets) in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
            data = data.to(device=device)
            targets = targets.to(device=device)
            
            # forward
            output = model(data)
            loss = criterion(output, targets)

            # backward
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()

            # gradient descent or adam step
            optimizer.step()
        per_epoch_train_duration.append(time.time() - epoch_time)
        accuracy = check_accuracy(test_loader, model, device)
        per_epoch_with_val_duration.append(time.time() - epoch_time)
```

I ran my docker with these commands

```
docker -it --shm-size=8gb /bin/bash
```

I am not sure why it hangs

Comment: How do you report the results?  How do you actually install the application in the Dockerfile and run it (why are you overriding the image's `CMD` with `/bin/bash`)?  Does the approach in [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) help you?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added how I get the results from psutil. 
I install the application by getting it from Git actually.