# docker-compose running container with command but command only works manually in container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file that includes a service configured like:

```
py_publisher:
    build:
        context: ./client
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 3
#    entrypoint: "python3 mqtt_client.py"
```

The image is built from this Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /mqtt_client
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "mqtt_client.py"]
```

The home dir (`/mqtt_client`) of the container contains:

```
Dockerfile  mqtt_client.py  requirements.txt
```

The relevant docker-compose results:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                        PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
61b8f5e1e0bb   e1d0fc27a640   "python3 mqtt_client…"   7 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds                                                                                                                   mqtt-demo_py_publisher_1
9992b9c9031d   e1d0fc27a640   "python3 mqtt_client…"   7 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds                                                                                                                   mqtt-demo_py_publisher_2
a197f0f3126b   e1d0fc27a640   "python3 mqtt_client…"   7 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds                                                                                                                   mqtt-demo_py_publisher_3
```

The issue is that the Python command is not actually "working".  Simply nothing happens.  However, when I `exec` into the containers and run that exact command, it works fine.

What's the difference in the way I'm running via docker-compose and running it manually exec'ed into the container?

Comment: The containers are "up" and the command shows as expected, so does your app not log anything when it starts?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no the app doesn't log anything but I know it's not working because I can check the results of what the Python script does in another app.  When I run it manually when `exec`'ed, it works fine.

Comment: Does the `python -u` option, or the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable, make a difference; is the process actually running, but buffering its output in-process?  (See for example [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker).)

Comment: I'm saying can you log/print anything in the client script's main method? Do the cotnainers actually remain up and not restart themselves? If `docker-compose logs` are empty, then it _seems_ like the command is exiting with an error

Comment: @DavidMaze no I've confirmed that the lack of output is because the script isn't being run at all.

Answer (score 0):

the proper way to do it, is by using entrypoint and the command. e.g.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["mqtt_client.py"]
```

since you are using python image already, you can drop the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction and only keep `CMD`.