# Python logs not showing when run via aiodocker

Tags: python, docker, logging, python-asyncio

I am following [aiodocker example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiodocker) by replacing `echo "hello world"` with `python -c 'print("hello world")'`, but the logs are not showing.

Below solutions (use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, `flush=True`, `-u` flag) do not help:

[Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker)

[Why doesn't my docker actually log anything?](https://serverfault.com/questions/940281/why-doesnt-my-docker-actually-log-anything)

```
import asyncio
import aiodocker

async def run_container():
    docker = aiodocker.Docker()
    container = await docker.containers.create_or_replace(
        config={
            'Cmd': ['python', '-c', 'print("hello world")'],
            'Image': 'python:3.8.2-buster',
        },
        name="testing"
    )
    await container.start()
    logs = await container.log(stdout=True, stderr=True)
    print(''.join(logs))
    await container.delete(force=True)
    await docker.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_container())
    loop.close()
```

What else can be wrong?

Comment: `'Cmd': ['python', '-c', 'print("hello world")']` does: `'Cmd': ['python', '-u', 'print("hello world")']` make any difference?

Comment: @user56700 `-u` flag does not help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please wait for the started container to finish before getting logs:

```
await container.start()
await container.wait()
```

Another option is using `follow=True` parameter for logs fetching:

```
async for chunk in container.log(stdout=True, stderr=True, follow=True):
    print(chunk)
```

It can be applied to the running container instance.