# Running python loop on a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I have this `python` application, which will run every 5 seconds (when executed as `python3 app.py`) but not expecting the same output when dockerized.

Here's my `app.py`

```
import os
import threading
from pymongo import MongoClient

# get the values of the environment variables 
MONGODB_HOSTNAME = os.environ['MONGO_URI']
MONGODB_USERNAME = os.environ['MONGODB_USERNAME']
MONGODB_PASSWORD = os.environ['MONGODB_PASSWORD']
MONGODB_DATABASE = os.environ['MONGODB_LOGS_DATABASE']
MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME = os.environ['MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME']

client = MongoClient("mongodb://"+MONGODB_USERNAME+":"+MONGODB_PASSWORD+"@mongodb/admin")

def get_count():

    threading.Timer(5.0, get_count).start()
    records = get_records()
    print("Getting count...")

    # Check if last 10 records have 10 failed attempts
    response_codes = list(map(lambda x : x['ResponseCode'], records))
    
    codes = []

    count = 0
    for response in response_codes:
        codes.append(response)
        if (response == '200'):
            count = count+1
    
    return str(count)

def get_records():
    db = client[MONGODB_DATABASE]

    collection = db[MONGODB_COLLECTION_NAME]
    cursor = collection.find()

    item = {}
    data = []

    if cursor:
        for record in cursor:
            item = {'ResponseCode' : record['ResponseCode']}
            data.append(item)

    return data


get_count()
```

When I try it, the output is as below:

```
Getting count...
<after 5 seconds>
Getting count...
<after 5 seconds>
Getting count...
<after 5 seconds>
.
.
.
```

And here's the `Dockerfile` for the above app

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine3.9

LABEL MAINTAINER="Jananath Banuka banukajananathjayarathna@gmail.com"

ENV GROUP_ID=1000 \
    USER_ID=1000

WORKDIR /tmp/

ADD . /tmp/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

When when I run and build and see the logs, I can only see the below output and nothing after that:

```
Getting count...
```

Can someone help me why it is only printing it once but not recurring?

PS: environment variables are passed in a `docker-compose.yml`

Thank you!

Comment: Do the solutions in [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) help you?

Comment: Yes David, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable below in order to force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```