# Kafka consumer script hangs when executed as a docker entrypoint

Tags: python, docker, kafka-python, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to connect a python kafka consumer to a kafka broker using the following script:

```
import kafka

from configuration import config


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('Start')

    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers=config.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
        auto_offset_reset =config.CONSUMER_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET,
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        group_id=None,
    )
    consumer.subscribe((config.CONSUMER_INPUT_TOPIC,))

    print('Listening')
    for msg in consumer:
        print('Message received')
```

I am executing that script as an entrypoint to a custom docker image.

This script works fine when executed from my local shell with `python script.py` or even when I execute it manually through docker using `docker-compose exec my_service python script.py` but it does not run at all when executed through the entrypoint. In the latter case not even the `Start` is printed! One more detail is that when `for msg in consumer:` block is removed the script gets executed and the prints show up.

I have tested it in two pc's and received the same results.

I have tried with the following python base images:

```
python:3.8.5
python:3.8.13
python:3.8.13-slim-buster
```

The output of `docker inspect <custom_image_name> | grep -A5 Cmd` is:

```
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"sh\" \"/entrypoint.sh\"]"
            ],
--
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "sha256:<sha256>",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "sh",
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster

COPY ./resources/requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install pip --upgrade \
    && pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY ./resources/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

and the `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python run.py
```

Comment: what you are getting on running `docker inspect image <image_name>|grep -A5 Cmd`

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: @arunpal Just edited to answer questions.

Comment: check if config is getting loaded properly. Also I believe you might have miss to build image again after doing changes. Or doing some typo in image building.

Comment: Does setting an environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` help?  Also see [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker).  (If this is the problem, I'd expect you to be able to see activity from the Kafka broker end.)

Comment: @DavidMaze that was it, (PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1). Could those logs block the main process?

Comment: No; if you print out enough log messages, the Python process will eventually write out a block of content.