# Multi-threading not working w/ Flask and Docker

Tags: python, multithreading, docker, flask

I'm having some issues with my application, which is supposed to run a function in the background every 10 seconds and handle requests simultaneously. To do so, I created a daemonized thread with `threading.Timer` recursively:

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Timer


def set_timer_and_start(i):
    print("Iteration", i)
    thread = Timer(10, set_timer_and_start, args=(i+1,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()


print("Starting app...")

app = Flask(__name__)

print("Starting thread")

set_timer_and_start(1)
```

The point is: this application is working when I'm running locally (directly on my machine).

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Starting app...
Starting thread
Iteration 1
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C%
```

But when I try to run it inside a Docker container, it doesn't work, and I don't get any message on the terminal before stopping the container. When I stop it, all the messages appear in the terminal like this:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 docker-image-test:latest
 * Serving Flask app '/usr/src/app/app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^CStarting app...
Starting thread
Iteration 1
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN pip install flask

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./app.py /usr/src/app/app.py

ENV FLASK_APP=/usr/src/app/app.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

CMD ["flask", "run", "--no-reload"]
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but what I want is to run a function in the background considering it's a Flask application and not necessarily related to the webserver (I need the webserver for other reasons, but it's also necessary to run this function in the background).

**Edit:**
I guess I found the problem: it seems that the thread is executing but the messages are not shown (for some reason). If so, why does `print` not work at the moment it's called (or, at least, the message is not printed)?

Comment: Is the problem that output isn't being printed on the container's output ([Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker)), that the container is unreachable ([Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)), something else?

Comment: It seems that the container is not executing the second thread before I try to stop the container. The output is just a way I tried to check this behavior. The container is reachable and I can access the webserver without problems.

Comment: I guess I found the problem: it seems that the thread is executing but the messages are not shown (for some reason). If so, why does `print` not work at the moment it's called (or, at least, the message is not printed)?

Comment: If you `docker run -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 docker-image-test`, does the `print()` output appear immediately?  That's the recommendation of the first question I linked to.

Comment: It works! Thank you and sorry for the misunderstanding.