# Docker container logging interval: logs are not being send as they are outputted by container

Tags: docker

I am building my first very simple container. The python script simply outputs the message with the number of seconds that have passed.

When I try to read the log using:
docker logs "container name"

I do get the logs, however, it seems like the logs are only sent to the log file at a certain interval. In my case, this interval is about 3.5 minutes. I want there to be a constant stream (so that when the container outputs x, it is immediately written to the log file.

Example of the log with timestamps: (only shows a small part)

```
...  
2022-08-09T09:46:24.677360000Z Waiting for file... 208 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:46:24.677364500Z Waiting for file... 209 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:46:24.677369700Z Waiting for file... 210 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:46:24.677388700Z Waiting for file... 211 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:46:24.677395900Z Waiting for file... 212 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:49:54.949131800Z Waiting for file... 213 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:49:54.949169300Z Waiting for file... 214 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:49:54.949176000Z Waiting for file... 215 seconds passed  
2022-08-09T09:49:54.949180700Z Waiting for file... 216 seconds passed  
...
```

Comment: what code is writing the logs? can you share it?

Comment: If it's in Python, [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) discusses this phenomenon.

Comment: It is indeed in python, and adding "-u" resolved as posted by David. Is there a way to post Davids comment as an answer to the question? (I am new to stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

use follow flag

```
--follow, -f
```

try it

```
docker container logs --follow  CONTAINER-NAME
```

relevant link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/#usage