# Docker container created but not starting UBUNTU

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I created my own image from python app:

```
import calendar

print('Welcome to calendar')


year = int(input('Enter year'))
month = int(input('Enter number of month'))

print(calendar.month(year,month))
print('Good bye')
```

Docker file:

```
FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
CMD [ "python","main.py" ]
```

After running comand docker run -it my-calendar (it's name of my image) i get back ID of my container, but it is not running. I dont know why.

I tried to do the same thing on Docker Desktop from Windows (with the same files python and Dockerfile) and it works correctly. I think it is problem in my ubuntu on virtual box. Can you help me?

Comment: When I try to reproduce your issue, the program works as it should.

Comment: Did you try on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm a little confused that you say that you get back the ID of the container when you run it. That's usually something to get when you have the `-d` option on your `docker run` command, but your command doesn't have that. I don't get the ID, when I run it.

Comment: Are you hitting [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker) maybe?