# Python Logger Not showing in Docker container Logs

Tags: python, docker, logging, docker-for-windows

I have a couple of containers running as a Spark Cluster.
When I am submitting my Python application, I made sure to have logging being managed by a the logging module.
However, I cannot see any of my logs on the container stdout/stderr.
How is this supposed to be configured?

This is how I am configuring my python logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(app_name)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # set logger level
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler() #set streamhandler to stdout
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

Had anyone faced the same situation? How to overcome?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running into [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker); does setting an environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` help?

Comment: You mean adding that env var in all cluster nodes?