# Docker: To get console output of my container [Python app inside]

Tags: python, docker, image, containers, virtual-machine

I have a docker container with python application. The container is hosted inside a VM. There are print statements within the python script, I want to see those print statements after running the docker image. How can I do that?

P.S. I have not assigned a port to the container and what I want to see is the previous output from the console.

`docker run --name container-runner --restart always -d image-name`

I tried:
`docker logs <container-id>`
but no luck.

Comment: Show us the output of the two command lines to help you.

Comment: Can you try to run your container without the -d flag, to run the container in the foreground and you'll be able to see its output directly in the terminal

Comment: Is your problem [Python app does not print anything when running detached in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/python-app-does-not-print-anything-when-running-detached-in-docker)?  If not, just the `docker run` command isn't really enough to debug what might be going wrong; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: The thing is I want to run the container in the background. I would have seen the output if I had run it in the foreground. By running in detached mode, I want to keep the output of the python script somewhere if possible and get back to it whenever I want. Hope that clarifies things :)