# Docker container doesnt show logs of process inside

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
CMD ["/opt/server/start-server.sh"]
```

start-server.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Launching Server"
./ServerApplicationIHaveNoControllOver 
echo "Finished Application"
```

I can verify that the server starts correctly and handle all the requests when executing docker-compose up, but i dont see any logs. For other containers i see the logs totally fine.

But if i run *start-server.sh* inside a normal shell, i can see every log message of that application

What is the different from having logs in a shell, but having no logs in a docker container?

My question is now, how can i "pipe" the logs of ./ServerApplicationIHaveNoControllOver  into STDOUT so it appears in the *docker logs CONTAINER_HASH* command?

EDIT: if the app server somehow has an error and finishes early, all the logs are flushed into STDOUT, so it looks like the process is keeping the logs and only releases them when the process finished

Comment: Is the application a Python application ([Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/why-doesnt-python-app-print-anything-when-run-in-a-detached-docker-container))?  You'll need to change the stdout buffering behavior of the application in some way.

Comment: no sadly its not a python application. I think its c++

Comment: `mybinary > /some/path/log/standardout_goes_here  2>  /some/path/log/standarderror_goes_here `   then mount output log dir when you launch the container