# Getting different results running python script through Dockerfile vs terminal within Container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to containerise a service which listens to a Google PubSub queue of urls, processes the data using some ML models and uploads the results to a firestore DB.

Locally it works as expected, however when it comes to building and running the docker container I see some very strange behaviour. When I run the server through:

`CMD ["python3", "urlQueueProcessor.py"]`

at the end of the Dockerfile, the script starts but doesn't behave as expected. Some console warnings/startup stuff from packages are printed, but it immediately hangs before reaching any of my code. If I try a print statement before my imports it never shows.

What's stranger is that if I enter the container and run the exact same command through the terminal it does exactly what I expect and starts the server. I made a [little script](https://pastebin.com/t9nRhL3d) to check the environments and when I run it through CMD and terminal they both show the same output.

Has anyone seen this before? Or is there any workaround that I can try? I've tried starting it through a .sh but it didn't make any difference. I've spent around 2 days on this with no luck so any help would be appreciated. Here's the [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/WJGEGQ8s)

Cheers.

Comment: can you provide more details?
- Dockerfile
- how have you connected inside the container? post the exact command

Comment: I find the container name with `docker ps`, then use `docker exec -it [container_name] /bin/sh` (in Windows cmd terminal). I linked the Dockerfile at the end of the post.

Comment: Does [Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/why-doesnt-python-app-print-anything-when-run-in-a-detached-docker-container) describe your issue?  If not, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] directly in the question and not behind links?

Comment: @DavidMaze The solutions from that thread actually worked, thank you. I can't believe the server was working all this time but just not able to print the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663459/why-doesnt-python-app-print-anything-when-run-in-a-detached-docker-container)  that @DavidMaze suggested turned out to be the same issue; the script was running correctly but none of my print statements were being shown in the logs (also making debugging attempts invisible).
Specifically, all I needed to do was change:

```
CMD ["python3", "urlQueueProcessor.py"]
```

to

```
CMD ["python3", "-u", "urlQueueProcessor.py"]
```